# Double links in database created by title

Tags: php, mysql, forms, seo, hyperlink

I have problem with double links in mydatabase.
I have in php file form for new posts. There is $_POST['title'] 
When people submit title php creates a new url to database from title. Problem is when users submit title that already exists in db, beacause php created double link. I would like to write a function that checks url and if it exists create another link for new post, for example: if exist /posts/new_link function create another, like: /posts/new_link_1.
I had this code:

```
$link = $_GET['url'];

$checkdb = mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `posts` WHERE `url`='$link'" ) or die("ERROR");
$howmanypost = mysql_num_rows($checkdb); //this is check links in db

if ($howmanypost = $newlinksfromtitle) { 

// Here I would like the function that creates a new url to db

} else {

$newpost = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`, `img`, `tags`, `author`, `data`, `type`, `url`) VALUES ('', '$title', '$img', '$tags', '$author', '$data', 'img', '$url')";
$makepost = mysql_query($newpost);

}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Nice SQL injection hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that all the posts with the same title have similar URLs, query for that:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string( $title);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `title` FROM `posts` WHERE `title`='$title'" );
$num_same = mysql_num_rows( $result);

if( $num_same > 0) 
{
    // We know there's at least 1 post with the same title, so change the URL
    $url = $url . '_' . $num_same; // Or: ($num_same + 1)
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`, `img`, `tags`, `author`, `data`, `type`, `url`) VALUES ('', '$title', '$img', '$tags', '$author', '$data', 'img', '$url')";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
```

Make sure that you're properly sanitizing your inputs so your strings are not subject to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank You for fast response, I try this